# How to speed up writing into Impala from Talend

Tags: talend, impala, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Big Data (7.3.1), and I write files from various sources to Cloudera Impala (Cloudera QuickStart 5.13) but that takes too much time and writes only ~3300 rows/s (take a look at the pictures).

[image: csv to impala]
[image: oracle xe to impala]
[image: impala output settings]

Is there way to raise writing to ~10000-100000 rows/s or even greater?
Am i using wrong approach for the load?
Or do i need to configure Impala/Talend better?
Any advice is welcome!

**UPDATE**
I install JDBC Impala driver:
[image]

But OutputFile looks like it not configured for Impala:
[image]

Error:
Exception in component tDBOutput_1 (db_2_impala)
org.talend.components.api.exception.ComponentException: UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION:{message=[Cloudera]ImpalaJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: **Impala does not support modifying a non-Kudu table: algebra_db.source_data_textfile_2**
), Query: DELETE FROM `algebra_db`.`source_data_textfile_2`.} at org.talend.components.jdbc.CommonUtils.newComponentException(CommonUtils.java:583)

Comment: Just thinking, are you using impala odbc driver or hive? They can make huge perf difference. Use impala native odbc/jdbc to connect to impala. Also you can increase commit interval to 100k, but if read is slow, you need fix that bottle neck first.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I installed Impala JDBC, made new connection, but output file looks diffrent. There is no overwrite (only delete which is not supported in Impala), and that rise error...

Comment: From log it is trying to delete from Impala table `DELETE FROM algebra_db.source_data_textfile_2`. Are you trying to delete?

Comment: I can't delete data from Impala (Impala doesn't support delete), clear data from table should be overwrite but JDBC output is set for like relational table, not for Impala or Hive table

Comment: Whats the infa sess doing? Ins/ upd/ del? Remove other options from target load property.